# Using static members to act as a namespace with templates : bad idea?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a question about design.

I have a series of generic functions that do not belong to the same object but act on the same complicated types.

I am thinking about grouping them in a templated class as static member functions for two reasons :

a) I can put typedefs into my "namespace class" so that code is more readable
b) The user can typedef the static class once and for all and then forget about specializing the functions.

So instead of calling :

`myfunction< char,int,std::set<double> >(...);`

He can do :

`typedef TheClass< char, int, std::set<double> > MyTheClass;`

and write :

`MyTheClass::myfunction(...);`

Would you consider this bad design and why?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Using an ordinary namespace & letting template argument deduction do its job doesn't work?

Comment: Yes and no, I'd still have to specify types when doing assignments - or using auto but I far prefer having a meaningful type name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think wherever you can apply the DRY principle it is usually a good idea, so if this allows you to avoid repeatedly passing the same template parameters, and you can't find a cleaner alternative, then go for it.

Answer (score 2):

A template function in a class will only be instantiated if it is used. So, even though you're wrapping all your functions in a template class, it wouldn't be inefficient as only the ones that are used with a specific type parameter set will be instantiated for the template with that type parameter set.

On a readability note, I personally despise typedefs except in rare circumstances because you end up having to chase them down to figure out what your types are, and when you have a lot of them for a templatized class taking varying type parameters, it can get frustrating and hard to read anyway.

Maybe wrap functions that have a similar purpose in a real namespace of their own that you can introduce with a using clause when you want to use them, and make another namespace for optional typedefs a user can introduce separately for those functions :)